# How to slice a unicode object?

Tags: python, unicode, slice

I was trying to get a unicode string from my database and slice it to get part of it.

However I get:

```
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

Code:

```
info = post.body(0)[0:50]
```

Here `post.body(0)` is a {unicode} variable.

I want the first fifty characters of it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `post.body` is the unicode string and you try to call it with `post.body(0)`, which fails. Slicing unicode strings is not a  problem.

Comment: are you sure body.post(0) is a unicode object?

Comment: Yeah. I find it's a pretty silly question. It is because I met a similar problem where I got a tuple from the database and I had to use index to get the value. I mixed them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`post.body` is already a unicode object. Python is complaining that you are trying to call it with argument `0`.

So, just try

```
info = post.body[0:50]
```